# Unable to get the conditions right

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, 2d

**I am trying to make a program of a bouncing ball. I have tried some conditions in it.But i have not got what i wanted.The ball keeps on moving back and forth in the diagonal direction of the frame.Where is the problem ? I have highlighted the main logic of this program.**

*Here is the program :*

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MovingBall2D extends JPanel{
 int x_Pos=0;
 int y_Pos=0;
 int speedX=1;
 int speedY=1;
 int diameter=30;
 int height=30;
 int frameX=500;
 int frameY=500;

 MovingBall2D() {
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if( x_Pos > ( frameX - diameter ) ) {       //  <------ logic starts from here
      x_Pos =  frameX - diameter;
      speedX = -1; 
    }
    else if(x_Pos < 0) {
      x_Pos = 0;
      speedX = 1;
     }
    else if( y_Pos > ( frameY - diameter ) ) {
      y_Pos =  frameY - height; 
      speedY = -1;
     }
    else if(y_Pos < 0) {
     y_Pos = 0;
     speedY = 1;
    } 
    x_Pos = x_Pos + speedX;
    y_Pos = y_Pos + speedY;    
    repaint();
   }
  };
  new Timer(10,taskPerformer).start();   // <------- logic ends here
 }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 super.paintComponent(g);
 g.setColor(Color.red);
 g.fillOval(x_Pos,y_Pos,diameter,height);
}
}

class Main2D {
 Main2D() {
 JFrame fr=new JFrame();
 MovingBall2D o = new MovingBall2D();
 fr.add(o);
 fr.setSize(500,500);
 fr.setVisible(true);
 fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
  new Main2D();
 }
}
```

**EDIT -** Ball moves back and forth. **Why this happens?** I expect the output [shown here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/45examples/40animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.shtml).
*If the question is unclear to any one please compile and then run to see the output .*

Comment: could you explain what you are getting? and what you want to get?

Comment: Well... what is it that you want? You should describe exactly what you are seeing (What is the problem?) and exactly what you want to see (What would be a solution?). Is the ball going off screen? Is the ball bouncing, but still going off screen before it bounces on certain angles? Is the window not showing up at all? We have no clue what kind of answer you desire. Help us help you :)

Comment: @ Hunter I am trying to make the program of the bouncing ball. I expect the output shown here in this applet http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/45examples/40animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.shtml

Comment: what output i want is shown here in this applet http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/45examples/40animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ball starts at position 0, 0.  At each time step from then until it hits a wall, its x position and y position each increase by 1.  So at time 471, its position is (471, 471).  At this point both the x and y conditions for turning around are true, so both get switched and the ball turns completely around.

If you change the starting position to something like (0, 30) or change one of the speeds to something other than 1 or -1 you will see that your code works.  The ball will always be following some loop, but because of the frame size and ball placement yours happens to be very small.

However, I would suggest that you remove the else conditions.  It is possible in a single frame for the ball to be too far left and too far down, so in that frame both conditions should be fixed, not just one.  Also, you may notice the ball continuing off the screen in the y direction.  This is because your main frame is set to the same height as the panel.  The frame height includes the portion used for the top window bar, so it needs to be slightly larger than the panel it is holding.

Comment: yeah the ball continues off the screen in y direction and also in x direction.What can i do to avoid this.?

Comment: To avoid this you need initialize your JFrame to be slightly larger in the y direction.  I'm not sure exactly how much larger, something like 40 pixels though.  Play around with it.

Comment: To get the frame to exactly contain the panel use setPreferredSize() on the MovingBall2D class.  For example in the constructor you say setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(frameX, frameY)).  Then instead of explicitly calling fr.setSize() on your main frame use fr.pack().  That will automatically size the frame.

Answer (score 2):

In all four of your cases, you set the corresponding speed to -1:

```
speedX = -1;
//...
speedY = -1;
```

But you only want it to be negative when X is greater than the width or Y is greater than the height.  In the other two cases, you want the speed to be positive.

Or, maybe what you were going for was

```
speedX *= -1;
```

Which would toggle the speed to the opposite direction.

Comment: @ Mark Peters but now the ball moves back and forth.I just dont want the ball move back and forth.I want the output shown here in this applet (http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/45examples/40animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.shtml)

Comment: @ Mark Peters i've edited my question making speed=1 when x<0 and y<0

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that `speedX` and `speedY` are not properly updated. I think it should be like this instead:

```
if( x_Pos > ( frameX - diameter ) ) {       //  <------ logic starts from here
  x_Pos =  frameX - diameter;
  speedX = -1; 
}
else if(x_Pos < 0) {
  x_Pos = 0;
  speedX = 1;
 }
else if( y_Pos > ( frameY - diameter ) ) {
  y_Pos =  frameY - height; 
  speedY = -1;
 }
else if(y_Pos < 0) {
 y_Pos = 0;
 speedY = 1;
} 
x_Pos = x_Pos + speedX;
y_Pos = y_Pos + speedY;
```

Comment: i have edited my question.Making speed = 1 ball moves back and forth.I want the output shown here in this applet (http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/45examples/40animation/40BouncingBall/bouncingball.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have all the logic right, but your initialization makes it sure to bounce diagonally (from bottom left to top right)

Change them up, use random values OR hardcode them like so

```
 int x_Pos=100; // These are changed so the ball no longer starts at bottom left
 int y_Pos=20;
 int speedX=1;  //This should be fine as long as your initial position is different
 int speedY=1;
 int diameter=30;
 int height=30;
 int frameX=500;
 int frameY=500;
```

I also think this would work

```
int x_Pos = 100* Math.Rand(1);
```

etc.

Comment: what is this `int x_Pos = 100* Math.Rand(1);` ? this gives an error.

Comment: Oh that was kind of just pseudo code (not syntactically correct) ... basically whatever the Rand() function does (usually it returns a number from 0 to 1) you multiply it to get a required bounds and then you can get any number.  Just find documentation form Math.Rand().